# localhost/test.php returns nothing

Tags: php, html, web-applications, localhost

I am following a tutorial ["PHP & MySQL for dummies"](http://doha.ac.mu/ebooks/Computing/PHP%20&%20MySQL%20For%20Dummies.pdf) to build a web application. I created a simple `test.php` file in web space (`/var/www/html`). The problem is that when I type `localhost/test.php` in the browser address window, it returns me an empty page. I tried `localhost/php.info` and it worked well but I could not find why `test.php` does not work.

This is the test.php code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>This is an HTML line
 <p>
 <?php
    echo “This is a PHP line”;
    phpinfo();
 ?>
 </body></html>
```

I do appreciate any information.

Thanks.

Comment: empty page means no error ?

Comment: check the source code of the html you get

Comment: although I don't see it doing much, try and change the second <p> to </p>.  Also, comment out the PHP, run locally (in browser) confirming it works, then the same on the server.  If it then returns try and add back the PHP.  Process of elimination.

Comment: @RyanBabu: yes, No erro, just an empty page, html is empry as well

Comment: restart your server and then try it

Comment: in order for me to help you could you fill me in on a couple things?
1. Do you have apache running and php installed?
2. What happens when you right click the empty page and choose view source? EDITED
3. Did you copy and paste the code from the tutorial? IF so retype the quotes.

Comment: can you please tell your calling URL format

Comment: 1. yes I have apache2 running and php installed   2.when I write click again the html is empty

Comment: ok can you install chrome and check the developer console network tab(while refreshing), you will see what code the page is returning.  https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: Please see the new edit.

Comment: @Boopathi: I receive this error while restarting apache : Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/tutorial.com/public_html] does not exist
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

Comment: Also while you're learning, this site will be helpful for debugging these errors http://3v4l.org/ .

Comment: Mitchell - In the future, please try to ask your clarification questions in comments and provide just the solution and explanation in your answer. Thanks and happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that you put your script in /var/www/html

So the link might be

localhost/html/test.php

Also check the error log file for PHP error.

```
# cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

EDIT: Change your quote, ” are for Word document and not programming ;-)

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>This is an HTML line</p>
 <?php
    echo "This is a PHP line";
    phpinfo();
 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No even with localhost/html/test.php
it did not work :(

Comment: Do you have anything in the error file ?
Have you tried to restart apache ? "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart"

Comment: I checked the error log: this is the error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/test.php on line 9

Comment: Maybe try to reinstall the environment with this tutorial http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/lamp#alternative_2installation_des_paquets_methode_recommandee

Comment: when I try to restart apache I receive this error: (I never received this error before) Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/tutorial.com/public_html] does not exist
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

Comment: Ok, you just have to change your double quote “ and ” by this one ".
It's an encoding issue...

Comment: I don't recommend PHP&MySql for dummies, it's not the best book to learn for scratch. To many thing at the same time for nothing...
You can check this website to learn the basics http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php

Comment: thanks alot! the problem was solved by changing double quotes to "" :)

Answer (score -1):

I have tried with this..just type the word localhost followed  with name of the work eg.. localhost/test.php in the navigate bar on your browser then click enter